# Sensu/Uchiwa - No 'checks' listed

Tags: monitoring, puppet, rabbitmq, sensu

I've configured Sensu and Uchiwa using Puppet. I have clients reporting in, and raising events when checks fail.

I have checks in my server's `/etc/sensu/conf.d/checks/` folder, created by Puppet, for things like ping checks etc.
Example:

```
{
  "checks": {
    "check-ping-controller.local.net": {
      "subscribers": [ "sensu" ],
      "standalone": false,
      "interval": 60,
      "handlers": [ "default" ],
      "command": "/usr/lib64/nagios/plugins/check_ping -H 192.168.66.125 -w 100.0,60% -c 200.0,90% "
    }
  }
}
```

If I look at the server in the 'clients' page of Uchiwa (because it's also running the sensu-client to monitor itself), I see the checks listed there. However, nothing shows up in my actual 'checks' page - it would be nice to see what's running across the datacentre!

Is anyone familiar with this and knows what issue I might be hitting? I'm running Uchiwa 0.4 and Sensu 0.16, on Centos 6.5.

UPDATE:
In the last 20 minutes I've done a 'flushall' in redis, and made some changes to nodes (deprovisioned one) that caused a refresh of the Sensu services. This seems to have now fixed the problem, and checks are appearing! I'm guessing it was the redis 'flushall' command, but I'm not familiar with Redis and don't know why that would have helped...

Any ideas SF?

Answer (score 2):

The solution for me was to restart the sensu-api service.

Once I did that the publish-subscribe checks appeared in my Uchiwa dashboard on the Checks screen. I'm using Sensu 0.21, Uchiwa 0.14.1 on CentOS 7.2. I admin I don't know why the sensu-api service restart is necessary.

I tried separately restarting the sensu-server service and flushing the redis db, neither of which had an effect on the uchiwa dashboard for me.

Comment: Same here. Had to restart sensu-api for the new checks to show up.